# Is allowing PDF file uploads from users of my web app a security risk?

Tags: python, security, pdf, file-upload

I maintain a small [open-source Flask extension](https://github.com/jeffwidman/flask-uploads) that makes handling file uploads more convenient.

One of the features is that out of the box it provides groups of filetypes such as images, documents, etc so that a developer can easily modify the behavior of all file extensions within that group.

I've received several requests to include `*.pdf` in the [documents group](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/#flaskext.uploads.DOCUMENTS).

Is this a security risk?

I seem to recall a few hacks happening way back in the day when someone opened a malicious PDF.

The documents group already includes files like .doc, .docx, .odf, .xlsx, etc

Comment: .doc and .xlsx are a much larger security risk. Any document from unknown source should be handled with care.

Comment: Understood, it was already this way when I inherited the maintainer role. Just trying to verify that I'm not opening a new vector that's commonly exploited even when the dev exercises reasonable caution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the contributing factors to how risky a file-format is how many "readers" can actually open that format. A security risk isn't necessarily in the format itself, it's in the program that opens the file and doesn't read that file in a "defensive" manner (opens itself to buffer overflows for example).

For example, historically only Microsoft Word could open .doc files meaning that if a vulnerability was found in Microsoft word, all .doc users were affected. So historically, many attacks were targeted towards the .doc format.

PDF has a very wide range of readers (Adobe, built-in Chrome PDF, built-in Firefox PDF, built-in Gmail PDF->HTML renderer, Fox-it, Evince etc.). PDF itself should be secure, and due to the wide variety of PDF readers it is even harder for a malicious hacker to stage an assault using PDF. There are much more "low-hanging fruit" document formats out there.

Comment: Great answer. I hadn't thought about how vulnerabilities are dependent on the client, not just the format.